# Asp.net web API: return object that contains more than one object

Tags: asp.net, xml, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I can Get() a single view model but when I have a View model that contains multiple view models the object does not return. I can also Get() and array of single models.

When I debug I can see the that view model does contain the data, even up to the return. But just an empty {} object gets to the client. I think that there is something fundamental I do not know. Do you have to serialize the view model to JSON or XML when the view models are bit more complex? If so can someone point me in the right direction?

Am I going about this the wrong way? Should I make a web API for each model and if I want the models associated with that model then I will be making two calls instead of one?

Ideally I want a single API that pulls a model and its associated models doing only one call to the server. Unless that is not recommended.

Example:

```
public BookVM GetBookAndChapters(int id)
    {
        Book book = db.Books.Find(id);

        if (book == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }


        BookVM bookvm = new BookVM 
        {
            Book = book,
            Chapters = db.Chapters.Where(c => c.BookId == book.BookId).ToList()
        }

        return bookvm ;
    }
```

If I just ask for a Book I will get the correct return. If I just ask for the chapters I will get an array of chapters. If I ask for a BookVM that contains Book and Chapters I will get an {} empty object.

Comment: You have a local variable `book` that is of both type `Book` and `BookVM`. Does the above code compile without errors?

Whether you should return chapters along with a book sounds like an API decision - is it likely that consumers of the API will always or nearly always want chapters of a book in addition to the book? If they do, including them is reasonable, otherwise don't. Clients can always batch requests to the API to fetch both the book and chapters with two separate API calls in one request roundtrip.

Comment: That code is not the exact code actually. It does compile with no errors.

Comment: I am making a separate web API for the chapters regardless. In most case the chapters and book will need to be returned. In fact other models will come along with it as well. Is it best to make separate calls and not just one?

Comment: Like I said, it depends on typical usage. It's a trade-off between Payload sizes vs. Frequency of requests. If clients can batch requests however and you configure web api to support it (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/introducing-batch-support-in-web-api-and-web-api-odata.aspx), then I would personally keep the API focused and the responses specific and small.

Comment: I found the issue. It is embarrassing though. Didn't have BookVM properties Public. You would have caught it had I posted the real code. Lesson learned.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that batch request though. That is very cool.

Comment: Good job! I'm going to vote to close the question now as it is specific and answered. Unless you can close it :)